# Использование c++ в микроконтроллерах

Tags: c++, avr-gcc, микроконтроллеры

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли использовать C++ для программирования микроконтроллеров?

Есть ли при этом какие либо ограничения для языка C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

использовать часто можно, но нужно смотреть на конкретную реализацию. К примеру, может не быть исключений.

С другой стороны, с++ приносит определенный оверхед, а на микроконтроллерах часто бывает важный каждый байт, это не java c большими серверами, где можно докупить планку-другую.

Но микроконтроллеры не стоят на месте и развиваются, как собственно и компиляторы. Возможно, для Вашего контроллера и Вашего случае С++ - лучший вариант.

Answer (score 3):

C++ не только можно, но и нужно использовать для программирования микроконтроллеров. Как тут писалось, никаких исключений и операторов new. Для отмены исключений есть даже флаг компилятора, специально для нас.
Чем С++ лучше си:

1. Строгая типизация. Если что-то не так, получите ошибку при компиляции, а не поиск её в отладке. Наглядный пример, если в функцию передаётся тип перечисления, а вы в си вписали что-то не то (int, к примеру), то в си вы пройдёте компиляцию, в C++ получите ошибку компиляции.
2. Ссылки. Философия С++: "не плати за то, что тебе не нужно". Ссылки не занимают место в памяти, код с ссылками смотрится аккуратнее, чем код с указателями. Всегда можно забыть поставить * или &.
3. Классы (структуры). Банально удобно описывать не только саму структуру, но и действия с ней. Каждый регистр можно обернуть в классовую обёртку с методами, которые своим названием указывают, что вы делаете. Если код необходимо много комментировать, то это плохой код.
4. Объекты. В функцию (класс, метод класса) можно передать ссылку на объект вывода микроконтроллера, а не писать кучу дефайнов всех регистров (легко ошибиться, много исправлять, особенно для всяких stm32).
5. Шаблоны. Забудьте про многострочные макросы, ошибки в которых отладить крайне сложно, дебагер в них просто не войдёт. Шаблоны куда лучше препроцессора.
6. Оверхеда нет. Это распространённый миф. Грамотный код, написанный на с++ даёт меньший объём бинарников, натыкался на исследования, даже ролики с конференций есть на ютьюбе. (полагаю всему виной ссылки вместо указателей и оптимизация шаблонов).

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле никаких ограничений нет, просто нужен правильный скрипт линковщика с соответствующими секциями для поддержки исключений и виртуальных методов, а так-же релизация аллокаторов/деаллокаторов и STL (конечно это роскошь?). Найти какой скрипт в сети не сложно...

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/100475)

Comment: Не понимаю претензии. Каков вопрос таков и ответ. Вопрос был можно или нет и есть ли ограничения. Ответ дан!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на язык Wiring, используемый в Arduino.
Это C++ без стандартной библиотеки и исключений, со своей специальной библиотекой. Компилируется он, кстати, упомянутым у вас в тегах avr-gcc.